# File never renamed, yet git log shows different output with --follow option

Tags: git

I made a commit `9ffff` which is a commit of changes for one file, `myfile.c`.  This file has never been renamed.

When I run a `git log myfile.c` I cannot see the commit `9ffff` in the output of this command.  When I run a `git log --follow myfile.c`, however, I see the commit `9ffff` in this command preceded by a merge commit `8ffff`.

The `--follow` option `continues listing the history of a file beyond renames (works only for a single file)` according to the `git` reference documentation.  Given the above, how is it possible the `--follow` option shows me the `9ffff` commit when the file `myfile.c` has not ever been renamed?

Answer (score 2):

Check what the docs say about specifying a path, in particular the reference to history simplification.  Most common way to get what you're looking at is to make a change, revert it, and then merge.  Git won't show you the change and the revert, since the combination has no effect so they're almost certainly not why you're inspecting the logs.  If you do want to see even commits that wind up having no effect, add `--full-history`.